# Magento 2 : How to create a non cacheable block

Tags: magento2, blocks

How Should I create a block without cache?
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blocks can be set as non-cacheable by setting the cacheable attribute false in layout XML files.

For example,

```
<block class="Block\Class" name="blockname" cacheable="false" />
```

Pages containing such blocks are not cached.

Just add this `cacheable=”false”` into the XML file like:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <body>
      <referenceContainer name="content">
         <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Classname" name="blockname" template="Vendor_Module::filename.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
      </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

You can use `cacheable=”false”` attribute in your layout to disable cache for block.

**Note:-** Pages containing such blocks are not cached.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use this property of block for that

```
cacheable='false'
```

In to your xml file added block like this :

```
<block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Classname" name="blockname" template="Vendor_Module::filename.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
```